# Enable `CanUserAddRows` with dynamically created `DataGrid` columns - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The `DataGrid` columns are dynamically created in code behind. In order to bind the columns dynamically I have a `Dictionary<string, obj>` property, with the key as the column header, and the values.

and the columns gets bound to the dictionary like this:

```
var item = new DataGridTextColumn();
item.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
item.Header = name;
item.Binding = new Binding($"di[{name}].obj") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
```

It works fine, but I couldn't figure out how to get the values from the new row form `DataGrid`

Comment: Is your DataGrid binded to a collection? New items should appear there. There also should be a string indexer in Columns collection. For example `dataGrid.Columns["column name"]`

Comment: @opewix Yes, Usually each column is bound to a property form the Source collection, where in my case all the columns are bound to a single property. which is the dictionary, each cell inside the row is a value from a dictionary, where the key is the column name. and the values is always empty when end the edit.

Comment: Some time ago I had to work with dynamic columns in Silverlight. I used `List<ExpandoObject>` for dynamic bindings. Consider to use it if there would be no answers

Comment: @opewix I will try it , thanks :)

Comment: @opewix I did change my code to use `ExpandoObject`, same proplem, it all works fine, but the added item to the `List` does not contains the entered values. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: please see code example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I've created a test project and ExpandoObject worked for me. I was able to display dynamic column "FirstName" and also add new rows by editing grid rows

XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,56" Loaded="Grid_Loaded_1">
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="220" Width="389"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="339,286,0,-45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel Vm { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Vm = new ViewModel();
        Vm.Items = new ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>();
        DataContext = Vm;

        var fieldName = "FirstName";
        var item = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        item.Add(fieldName, "Adam"); // Dynamically adding new fields

        var eoItem = item as ExpandoObject;
        Vm.Items.Add(eoItem);

        // Dynamically adding new columns
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        col.Header = fieldName;
        col.Binding = new Binding(fieldName) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem some time ago. Below You can find my solution. Basically I needed to change AddingNewRow event. You will need to change types etc. to meet your needs but this should be rather easy.

```
private void AddingNewRow(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    DictionaryRowData newRow = new DictionaryRowData();
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryData.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        newRow.Cells.Add(new DictionaryCellData());
    }

    e.NewItem = newRow;
}
```

Sorry, for not matching exactly your case, but I don't have time right now. I hope it will help